# Make DIV stylized as textarea and containing formatted text editable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this div:

```
<div class="textarea"></div>
```

which I stylized as textarea with this css:

```
.textarea {
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font: medium -moz-fixed;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    height: 28px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    resize: both;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Now, If I add some html code inside this div, even the cursor is not shown there. Can I make this div editable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the `contentEditable` attribute to true, and you're sorted

```css
.textarea {
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font: medium -moz-fixed;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    height: 28px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    resize: both;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea" contentEditable="true"></div>
```